# Can a StackPanel set itself to the height of its content?

Tags: wpf

I have WPF StackPanel which I want to resize its height according to the height of its contents.   Is there any native way to do this?   StackPanel doesn't seem to support "SizeToContent"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StackPanel` will always grow and shrink according to its contents, but what you end up seeing could be constrained by what contains the `StackPanel`, such as a `Window`.

Comment: I agree, put the StackPanel inside a ScrollViewer and you will see the stackpanel at full size, but with scroll functionality.

Comment: I see what I was doing wrong.  The trick is to not give it a height at all.   I was thinking I had to give it some "magic value" for height like "Auto" or "*"   Thanks.